# Язык с семантикой Python и Си-подобным синтаксисом

Tags: python, c

Подскажите такой язык (если такой есть).

Comment: Странное желание. Наоборот я бы ещё понял.

Answer (score 2):

Go  (надергано с python, С и еще по мелочи) 
развлекается им Google

Answer (score 0):

Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, больше всего подходит JavaScript. В особенности, начиная с [версии 1.7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/new_in_javascript_1.7), где были добавлены многочисленные конструкции (такие как генераторы) во многом схожие с python'овскими.